# How to make a canvas (rectangle) in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to make a windows canvas type rectangle, here is an image if you are having issues understanding what i mean,

[image: a busy cat]

Is there any way todo this in wxpython? ( also, is there a way to set it to automatically adjust to the window width -20px?, so a radius around the window, and will adjust to the users window size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I asked on the wxPython IRC channel and a fellow named "r4z" came up with the following edit to my code which worked for me on Windows 7.

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnPaint(self, event):
        """"""
        pdc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        try:
            dc = wx.GCDC(pdc)
        except:
            dc = pdc

        w, h = self.GetSizeTuple()
        w = w - 10
        h = h - 10

        dc.Clear()
        dc.DrawRectangle(x=5, y=5, width=w, height=h)


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def OnSize(event):
    event.EventObject.Refresh()
    event.Skip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = wx.Frame(None, title="Test")
    panel = MyPanel(frame)
    frame.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, OnSize)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Alternately, you might look at the wx.StaticBox widget.

EDIT #2: You could also just set the frame's style like this and skip the whole OnSize business:

```
frame = wx.Frame(None, title="Test", style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)
```

Comment: I added a fix to it that I got via wxPython's IRC channel